# Why is my nsmutuablearray still null?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I do not understand why my NSMutuableArray is null? Am I missing something? I am storing a string from parse in the array.
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
.h file

@interface IncomeTransactionViewController : UIViewController  <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    NSDate *myDate;
    NSMutableArray *accountArray;
    UIPickerView *accountPicker;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dateField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *accountField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *categoryField;

- (IBAction)hidekeyboard:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)addTransaction:(id)sender;
@end

.m file

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"startingBalance"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        accountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            [accountArray addObject:object[@"name"]];
            NSLog(@"%@", object[@"name"]);

        }

    }
     ];
```

Comment: what your NSLog Displays in console...?

Comment: Also, what's in the `NSArray` `objects` in your block? Have you verified that it's not empty?

Comment: NSLog displays names... when i run this NSLog(@"%@", [accountArray objectAtIndex:0]); I get null

Comment: initialize the array  in viewDidload

Comment: can you attach `NSLog(@"%@", object[@"name"]);` in your question that what it actually log?

Comment: plz attach your NSLog output to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are checking for accountsArray right after you start the query, it will be nil because the query is asynchronous and its callback won't be called until it completes.

If this is your code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query orderByDescending:@"startingBalance"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    accountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        [accountArray addObject:object[@"name"]];
        NSLog(@"%@", object[@"name"]);

    }

}];
int ct = [accountArray count];
```

Then ct will be 0 and accountArray will be nil, but when the callback is called, accountArray will have been allocated and populated. The correct answer that has been mentioned before, which i'll iterate here with a better explanation, is to allocate the array in viewDidLoad. Alternatively, you can allocate it before the query call:

```
accountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query orderByDescending:@"startingBalance"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        [accountArray addObject:object[@"name"]];
        NSLog(@"%@", object[@"name"]);

    }
}];
int ct = [accountArray count];
```

Or you can perform whatever you need to do with the array inside the block:

```
accountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Account"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query orderByDescending:@"startingBalance"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        [accountArray addObject:object[@"name"]];
        NSLog(@"%@", object[@"name"]);

    }
    int ct = [accountArray count];
    NSLog(@"Array countents: %@", accountArray);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. How do I access the NSMutableArray outside of the block?

Comment: since it's a member variable of your class it should be accessible.